# Display all days of a week using coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

Is there a way to display all the days of the week using coldfusion from Sunday through saturday. Any pointers will be appreciated thanks

Comment: This could prove to be helpful http://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/10/constructing-query-with-data-in-one.html

Comment: For next time, looking over the [Functions by Category](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1a60c-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6986) list often gives you a good idea of how/which functions you might use to approach tasks like this.

Comment: As @DanBracuk indicated, always try to type the constant strings manually  in your code instead of doing it programmatically, unless you have no option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<cfoutput>
  <cfloop from="1" to"7" index="dow">
    #dayOfWeekAsString(dow)#
  </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```